# How to execute 'ls-remote --heads origin master' in python?

Tags: python, git

I have some basic python script inside my git repo.
First I test some git command in my repo:

```
$ git ls-remote --heads origin master
a5dd03655381fcxxxx4e759ceba7aeb6456 refs/heads/master
```

Now I want to execute the same command in Python:

```
 if subprocess.call(["git", "ls-remote --heads origin master"]):
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("Not OK")
```

The output is:

```
git: 'ls-remote --heads origin master' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
OK
```

What am I missing?
When I just execute `ls-remote` in my python script it works:

```
a5dd03655381fcxxxx4e759ceba7aeb6456 HEAD
a5dd03655381fcxxxx4e759ceba7aeb6456 refs/heads/master
```

(I know the if statement is 'wrong/useless now').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to put every parameter in a separate item in the list.

```
import subprocess

if subprocess.call(["git", "ls-remote", "--heads", "origin", "master"]):
    print("OK")
else:
    print("Not OK")
```